# How to get decode details of jwt token in spring oauth use redis token store

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-oauth2

i've success got decode details use token store JwtTokenStore(JwtAccessTokenStore), but now it required to use redis so that i can revoke token.

here my code :

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new RedisTokenStore(redisConnectionFactory);
    // return new JwtTokenStore(defaultAccessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter defaultAccessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setAccessTokenConverter(new CustomJWTAccessTokenConverter());
    try {
        converter.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    converter.setKeyPair(this.keyPair());
   
    return converter;
}
```

and my customjwtaccesstokenconverter :

```
public class CustomJWTAccessTokenConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter  {

@Override
public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> claims) {
    OAuth2Authentication authentication
            = super.extractAuthentication(claims);
    authentication.setDetails(claims);
    return authentication;
   }
}
```

token enhancer :

```
@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    Map<String, Object> setAdditionalInformation = (Map<String, Object>) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(setAdditionalInformation);
    return accessToken;
}
```

i have no idea, when use redistokenstore. it didn't went to CustomJWTAccessTokenConverter because of that when i was trying to get additional information (decodeDetails) returned null.

```
 OAuth2Authentication authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
            Map<String, Object> decodeDetails = (Map<String, Object>) authenticationDetails.getDecodedDetails();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it resolved, but not sure it is the right way or not.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain chain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    chain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(customTokenEnhancer(), defaultAccessTokenConverter()));

    endpoints.exceptionTranslator(new OAuth2ExceptionTranslator())
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(chain)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new RedisTokenStore(redisConnectionFactory);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
    TokenEnhancerChain chain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    chain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(customTokenEnhancer(), defaultAccessTokenConverter()));

    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(chain);
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(new JwtTokenStore(defaultAccessTokenConverter()));
    tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(false);
    return tokenServices;
}
```

if anyone has better idea please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need configure token enhancer as well -

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new RedisTokenStore(redisConnectionFactory);
    // return new JwtTokenStore(defaultAccessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter defaultAccessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setAccessTokenConverter(new CustomJWTAccessTokenConverter());
    try {
        converter.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    converter.setKeyPair(this.keyPair());
   
    return converter;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
        // some code here
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
}

@Bean
@Primary
public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
   
    tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
    return tokenServices;
}

// Beans beans beans

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new YourCustomTokenEnhancer();
}
```

Comment: i already created it.

` @Bean`
    `public TokenEnhancer customTokenEnhancer() {`
`        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();`
    `}`

Comment: Ok, did you register it with AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer, you also need to to give your custom AuthorizationServerTokenServices  priority over default.

Comment: yes, here :
`public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {`
        `TokenEnhancerChain chain = new TokenEnhancerChain();`
        `chain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(customTokenEnhancer(), defaultAccessTokenConverter()));`

        `endpoints.exceptionTranslator(new OAuth2ExceptionTranslator()).tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenEnhancer(chain);`
}`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is here.

```
const decoded = jwt.decode(token, config);
console.log(decoded);
```

Also, you can return values.